# Why domain return different public ip when do a Ping

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a domain that is not working because of DNS. I checked it in https://dnschecker.org/ and https://who.is

Both sites return the correct IP server, but my domain it's not working. When I do it a `ping` in console with the command `ping www.example.com`, the console returns me an incorrect public IP.

Please see:

The public IP you see here is correct.

[image]

But when I ping it I received this (incorrect IP):

[image]

Is this something like cache DNS or something similar? Or why my public IP on my domain it's not refreshing up?

**UPDATE**

Now I'm getting this when a check it on `https://who.is` and I released `A` record shows without any reason, is there something to remove that record which is causing my website not working as well?:

[image]

Comment: Neither ping nor whois are adequate tools to troubleshoot DNS problems. You should use dig, or at least nslookup, nothing else.

Comment: not sure why you tried to hide the domain name, but you missed hiding it on the first line of output of `ping`.

Comment: The redacted text in your web screenshot does not appear to be long enough to match the domain you're pinging. Did you skip the `www` subdomain perchance?

Answer (score 13):

1. When you need a help with a particular domain DNS don’t try to hide its name. It doesn’t help with diagnostics.
2. The IP for festivaldeglobos.mx is 189.139.85.147 while the IP for www.festivaldeglobos.mx is 189.139.107.23 - you should make both the same.
3. Don’t mix CNAME and A records for the same name. It’s not permitted by the DNS specification and leads to unpredictable results like you see here.

[image: Final state]

BTW the festival looks like fun! I wish I could attend :)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you. I think it's cache because i don't have in my DNS Records any particular A records, i'm just using the CNAME because my public ip is a dynamic public ip, and until now, it's working fine. Just now at this moment festivaldeglobos.mx it's not working, but www.festivaldeglobos.mx it's, so i think is because all what you're writing me, so thanks for your reply

Comment: "Don’t mix CNAME and A records for the same name." No sane nameserver will allow to load such a zone anyway. A web interface allowing that is seriously broken.

Comment: @fernandourban You can’t use CNAME for festivaldeglobos.mx (without www) because there are other records (NS, SOA) and CNAME can’t be used in that case. I suggest you get some cheap or free hosting (e.g. AWS) with public IP and simply put that IP to the A records for both www and non-www DNS records. Hosting a website on dynamic IP is not a good idea.

Comment: Your recommendation to make both IPs the same lacks evidence that this is the right thing to do. How do you know the webserver is not hosted behind a different IP to the other services exposed through this domain?

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica in 9 out of 10 cases people want to resolve the same IP for both www and non-www. There is nothing to suggest that OP may need some special setup and needs it otherwise.

Comment: (a) You overstate how "special" that case is. (b) Nothing in your answer even touches on the possibility. You just say "you should make both the same". That is a false statement without evidence.

Answer (score 3):

Right now if you do an NSLOOKUP on the domain "www.festivaldeglobos.mx", you get a reply with a "CNAME" record pointing to the hostname "ns1.vuelosenglobos.mx", which is probably wrong... as it's unusual to have a www pointing to a nameserver, and also doesn't match what you have above.  In-turn, "ns1.vuelosenglobos.mx" returns an "A" record which points to "189.139.107.23".  Which is what you see above when you do "ping".  Why are you doing both a "CNAME" and an "A" record?  You cannot have both.

Comment: Thanks, i know already it's confuse use a CNAME but i don't know why who.is track that ip's because the only DNS Record i've configured into my web server is that CNAME, actually in this moment festivaldeglobos.mx it's now working but www.festivaldeglobos.mx does, so that's strang. I upvote this question because i did'nt know NSLOOKUP was helpful at this moment, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is generally the norm to have www and your apex/root domain pointing to the same place.  That's just to fall in line with how the web is generally used today.  There are very few instances where this is not the case.  Additionally, you should only run the site at one hostname, with www or without www, and redirect the other to it.

Since you have a dynamic IP, I wouldn't even configure the apex to point anywhere, make the www a CNAME of whatever address your public IP is, and call it a day.  Otherwise you are going to have this situation occur whenever your public IP changes, because you can only configure an A record for the apex domain.